# Entity frame work equivalent of nhibernate code

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate

With Nhibernate, I was able to override the framework method `GetLimitString` to provide my own paging implementation like you can see in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dagda1/306065d63cc99fa0b0f4).

Is there anything similar in the entity framework?

Comment: Are u looking for this `dbContext.Skip(1).Take(10).ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement paging in EF simply using Where().OrderBy().Skip().Take() - use Where to find the results, OrderBy to sort them, Skip(pagesize * page number) to go to the page you want, and Take to retrieve the pagesize of results, eg.

```
        var result = DB.SharedIPs
            .Include(o => o.SharedIPTags)
            .Include(o => o.IPType)
                .Where(ip => 
                    ip.IPStatus != Models.IPStatusEnum.Deleted &&
                    (ip.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchPhrase) || ip.Product.ToLower().Contains(searchPhrase) || ip.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchPhrase)))
                .Skip(page * numRows)
                .Take(numRows)
                .ToList();
```